# GPO edit mess , system error

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I messed around with a GPO editing tool in order to implement "hide computer drives" policy on windows 2003 server.
Since then I got a system error on my events log to say :

```
Windows cannot access the file gpt.ini for GPO CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=80TEST,DC=TEST. The file must be present at the location <\\80TEST.TEST\sysvol\80TEST.TEST\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini>. (Access is denied. ). Group Policy processing aborted.
```

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Any help is well accepted.
Thank you.

Comment: And the question is...?  Access is denied to `\\80TEST.TEST\sysvol\80TEST.TEST\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini`, so Group Policy processing is aborted. Not sure what's unclear in that error message.

Comment: The file exists... and I made the secure policy for the file is everyone to have full access... even with that I get this message.

Comment: What do you mean `I made the secure policy for the file is everyone to have full access`? Are you manually setting permissions on the GPO or the folder?

Comment: What permissions does the "80TEST.TEST\Users" group have to that file and the folder?

Comment: And what is this "GPO editing tool" that you were messing around with? Was it the GPMC?

Comment: I was trying to manually edit a file in order to appear more choices on the GPO "hide drives on my computer". I made a search in google and many have this problem because of DFS replication and other issues... I am not sure when this problem first appeared. I gave everyone access to this file to see if this I accidentally made any mistake when trying to edit tha GPO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the setting the GPO apply, erase the GPO and re-create it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice...but how can I know witch is the name of that GPO in order to delete it?

Comment: @Vagelism22678 - In your GPO's console, check the detail tab, you will see the id near the end, it's the same as the folder name !

Comment: Well seem that this police is the default domain policy and system do not let me delete it. I can modify it but not delete it...!!!

Comment: @vagelism22678 - Oh, its normal for that one, recover from a backup the directory before you edited it.